# Postponing timer schedule java

Tags: java, timer, delay, schedule, timertask

At `TIME = 0`, a user calls a method that sets a flag after 10 seconds. (at `TIME = 10`)

If the user calls the method again at `TIME = 2` the flag should NOT be set at `TIME = 10`, but instead at `TIME = 12`:

```
boolean myFlag; // initializes to false
private Timer timer;

public void setFlag() {
    // remove old timer if there was one
    if (timer != null) { timer.cancel(); timer = null; }

    // set the new timer
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() { myFlag = true; }
    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 10000);
}
```

Are there any cleaner ways to implement this "updated-schedule-time" model? Examples are appreciated.

Comment: so i understand you need an interval of 10 seconds between user's invoking a method and setting the flag?

Comment: That's right. Say the flag is initially false, and the user invokes the setFlag() method, the flag should be set 10 seconds after that, EXCEPT when the user (in that 10 seconds), invokes the method again, in that case, the delay has to start over. (I'll edit my post, the setFlag() method is not the same as the one in the run()).

Comment: ok listen, declare the Time from INSIDE the method. This will work for you.

Comment: Related? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

Answer (score -1):

I would have simply kept it the same but made little changes. 
Declare the variables always as variables should be declared and initialized near they are first used.

```
public void setFlag() {
    Timer timer;
    timer = new Timer();
    // remove old timer if there was one
    if (timer != null) { timer.cancel(); }

    // set the new timer
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() { setFlag(); }
    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 10000);
}
```